# Ad blocker blocks gtag get

Tags: google-analytics

I try to get the session_id of Google Analytics like this

```
const asyncGetSessionId = async (tracking) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof gtag === 'function') {
      gtag('get', (tracking || {}).googleAnalyticsIdGA4, 'session_id', (id) => {
        if (id) {
          resolve(id);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};

// Never reaches this point with ad blocker

const sessionId = await asyncGetSessionId(tracking);
```

With some activated ad blockers like uBlock the callback will never be executed and the page does not load. Our workaround is to set a timeout:

```
const asyncGetSessionId = async (tracking) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof gtag === 'function') {
      let googleTagManagerIsResolved = false;
      // wait 1sec for tag manager
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!googleTagManagerIsResolved) {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1000);
      gtag('get', (tracking || {}).googleAnalyticsIdGA4, 'session_id', (id) => {
        googleTagManagerIsResolved = true;
        if (id) {
          resolve(id);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

Is there a more elegant approach?